# Why my text input style does not update on re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to apply special styles to my text input when it is focused. I tried to implement this behavior by declaring `focused` as component state and re-rendering on focus/blur. However, it didn't work as expected.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

function App() {
  console.log("rendering...");

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  const inputStyles = [
    {
      maxWidth: 100,
      borderColor: "black",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    focused && { borderColor: "red" }
  ];

  const handleFocus = () => {
    console.log("focusing");
    setFocused(true);
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    console.log("unfocusing");
    setFocused(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}>Type something below</Text>
      <TextInput
        value="Hello"
        style={inputStyles}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      ></TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can see on the console that `handleFocus` and `handleBlur` are called correctly. I can see  that the component is re-rendering as well. However, the red border is not applied. What am I missing here?

The code is available for quick reproduction on code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mclaren-b0lwgl?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the outline was appearing above the input. Setting outline to `"none"` makes the border color change as I wanted.

Final version:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

function App() {
  console.log("rendering...");

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);

  const inputStyles = [{
    maxWidth: 100,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    outline: 'none'},
    focused && { borderColor: 'red'}
  ]

  const handleFocus = () => {
    console.log("focusing");
    setFocused(true);
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    console.log("unfocusing");
    setFocused(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}>Type something below</Text>
      <TextInput
        value="Hello"
        style={inputStyles}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      ></TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```